# Checking for invalid input

Tags: java

I'm having trouble detecting whether the user input exists.

```
boolean idFound=false;      
while((s = br.readLine()) != null){ 
    if (s.split(",")[1].contains(infoToRemove)) {
        continue;
    }                               
    wr.println(s);
    idFound=true;
}

if(idFound=false)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ID not exist","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

I tried this code, but the dialog doesn't appear if the ID does not exist.

Comment: @Tichodroma note that we must not fix OP's code in question, at most we can indent it.

Comment: Didn't you see that your question was *improved* by our edits? Why mangle it up again?

Comment: How to use if condition refer the following link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: Regarding your previous question on the hostel application: you will need to show work and ask a much more specific and answerable question it you want it to be answered and not closed down. Please have a look [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) for more tips on asking decent questions on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're displaying the message for every line that does not contain the ID. What you must do is display it if no line contains the ID. And you'll know that only

- when you have found the ID (which means that the ID exists), or
- when you have read all the lines without finding it (which means that the ID doesn't exist)

So, you should use a boolean variable `idFound` initialized to false, and loop until it has become true, or the end of the reader has been met. Then after the loop, you can tell if the ID has been found by examining the value of this boolean variable, and display the message if it's still false.

I won't provide code, because you should be able to figure that out by yourself.

EDIT: your updated code has two bugs:

```
if (s.split(",")[1].contains(infoToRemove)) {
    continue;
}
```

if I understood correctly, if the string contains infoToRemove, then it means that you have found the ID. So this is where the `idFound` variable should become true. You'd better not use continue and break. Instead cover all the possible cases with `if / else`.

```
if (idFound=false)
```

`=` is the assignment operator, not the equality operator. So it should be

```
if (idFound == false)
```

or, much better:

```
if (!idFound)
```

Comment: i have done the boolean method also,i send u the code,can u help me check?

Comment: Of course, edit your question with the new code below what you already have. But you should first test it by yourself. Use the method with known input that contains the ID, then with known input that doesn't contain it, and see if it behaves correctly in both cases.

Comment: i have edited and try.In this case,when id not found,it wont display anything